# Splitting CSV into one excel workbook but multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, csv, export

I am working on a csv file with more than 10 million rows.

Is there a way to convert such csv into one excel file having multiple sheets?

I am novice to programming so need support.

Thanks...

Comment: Ye, there is a way.But you should mention which technology you are going to use to manipulate Excel - Excel Interop? VB? A 3rd party suite of components, such as Aspose? Or what?

Comment: Is there a way? Yes. Is it worth it? No. Anything with 10M rows belongs in SQL
, not Excel.